Kubuntu 24.04 - Weird color profile
Last month I performed a fresh install of Kubuntu 24.04, which I mainly use for work. Sometimes I also use it for basic photo manipulation. Last week, I needed to color correct a few photos but I quickly found out that the system is using some weird color profile. Pictures tend to be a little bit too contrasted, and there is a significant amount of red tint. To the point where I'm unable to color-correct. At first I thought it was caused by the photoviewer, but this is not the case as Rawtherapee, nomacs and gwenview show the pictures exactly the same.
Yesterday I launched Windows: in there, the original photos looks decently good, as I expect them to be.
So I went back to Kubuntu (which is using X11), looked through the settings, but I couldn't find anything obvious that could change this behavior. I also uninstalled nvidia drivers and rebooted the system: now, it's using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source). Nothing changed. The tint is still there.
What else can I try to get some neutral color profile?

That's a typo..

So you have no driver for the unnamed GPU now?

Right now the system is using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

Please add this to the question with edit. The last thing the question says is video driver removed.
